# Ubuntu 18.04 corrupted driver - random place artefacts

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, bug-reporting

Lately when I load my Ubuntu it somehow load badly. It gives artifacts on random places of screen. What should I do?

My specs:

```
Linux max-desktop 4.18.0-16-generic #17~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12
13:35:51 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My hardware:

```
processor   AMD FX-8320E Eight-Core Processor
multimedia  Tobago HDMI Audio [Radeon R7 360 / R9 360 OEM]
multimedia  SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
```

My full `lshw` specs: https://pastebin.com/WfE6wnPd

How to send bug-report to Ubuntu? What else information do I need to obtain? And probably there is the solution to this problem.

Dota 2 also shows bad performance, but lately everything was OK.

Checked logs on `dmesg` it says GPU fault detected.

```
VM_CONTEXT1_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS 0x03025014
```

Repeats many times.

[example of artefact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XE1r.png)

Comment: hi, you graphics card would indicate that you switch to ubuntu 18.10 to take andvatage of the new mesa libs available on ubuntu 18.10 that help tremendously with Radeon / AMD graphics issues. would you be open to that? is the hardware what changed recently? if not can you think of any other reason why your ubuntu 18.04 worked before and does not now, or did ubuntu 18.04 not work before either, you're just comparing it to windows or another version?

Comment: Well I recently installed linux, sometimes it was behave like this, but this was cured by reboot. From now on problem became persistent.

Comment: okay that's a tiny bit more information than before but basically you've always had this problem on ubuntu 18.04. so would you be open to installing ubuntu 18.10 to see if the problem is still there? by the way do you know how to install the AMD grphic drivers?

Comment: No I don't know how to install AMD driver, I thout it already installed, didn't it?

Comment: no? ubuntu has a generic default driver called nouveau which is made to be compatible with almost anything, Nvidia, AMD, intel, The Simpsons... but realistically it's only meant to hold out in case gaming isn't your thing, and falls short alot, including right now. so I would advise you first install an AMD driver but again it really would only bear fruits with ubuntu 18.10 and up. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: I tried installing official radeon driver but gliches are still here sometimes.

Comment: humph, at least your Dota 2 performance should be much better now, there are two remaning solutions, upgrade your kernel : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ukuu -y && sudo ukuu` and updating to kernel 4.20 or switching to ubuntu 18.10.